# evaluating a sympy function at an arbitrary-precision floating point

Tags: python, sympy, mpmath

Given a sympy symbolic function, for example

```
x=symbols("x")
h=sin(x)
```

when one calls

```
h.subs(x, mpf('1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'))
```

sympy returns a floating point number.  The return value is not an mpf.

Is there a convenient way to get sympy to evaluate symbolic standard functions (like exponential and trig functions), using arbitrary precision?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To evaluate an expression, use `expr.evalf()`, which takes a precision as the first argument (the default is 15). You can substitute expressions using `expr.evalf(prec, subs=subs_dict)`.

```
>>> sin(x).evalf(50, subs={x: Float('1.0')})
0.84147098480789650665250232163029899962256306079837
```

Comment: Thanks, with a little modification your answer does what I'm looking for.  I need to generally change your Float('') creation to an mpf('') creation but that compiles as well.

Comment: Second comment: it appears a sympy Float is ?essentially? an mpf type.  So my first comment was neither here nor there.

Comment: Yes, Float is a wrapper around mpf, which is necessary so that it works correctly with SymPy functions. If you want to work with mpmath functions and types directly another option is to use `lambdify(x, sin(x), "mpmath")` which will convert the SymPy expression into a mpmath function, which can then be called with an mpf.